# IntelliJ Idea - Lost the option to select Spring Boot as a run configuration

Tags: intellij-idea

In IntelliJ Idea there used to be an option under run configurations to add a Spring Boot run configuration, but for some reason I no longer have that option.

How do I get the option back, or has it been removed?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the Spring Boot plugin was installed but disabled. I enabled it under Preferences > Plugins > Installed > Spring Boot